# Backbone Routing 404 Error

Tags: backbone.js, routes, http-status-code-404, slim

I have a backbone.js + slim php + jquery mobile app.

I search for university modules, pick one, then tap a link to produce a list of lecturers associated with the module. This works!

Now I want to be able to tap a lecturer list item to produce a lecturer details page and I am getting a 404 that I just can't figure out.

I think I have something wrong in how I am routing to the lecturer details

My API methods are:

```
$app->get('/modules', 'getModules');

$app->get('/modules/:id', 'getModule');

$app->get('/modules/search/:query', 'getModulesByName');

$app->get('/modules/:id/lecturers', 'getLecturers');

$app->get('/modules/:id/lecturers/:staffNumber', 'getLecturer');
```

Here I have getLecturers defined - pulling a list of lecturers associated with a module:

```
function getLecturers($id) {
    $sql = "select l.staffNumber, l.firstName, l.lastName, l.moduleNo1, l.moduleNo2, l.email, m.moduleNo
            from lecturertable l, moduletable m
            where m.moduleNo=:id AND (l.moduleNo1=:id OR l.moduleNo2=:id)";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $lecturer = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;

        if (!isset($_GET['callback'])) {
            echo json_encode($lecturer);
        } else {
            echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($lecturer) . ');';
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to get an individual lecturer by passing in a 'staffNumber':

```
function getLecturer($staffNumber) {
    $sql = "select l.staffNumber, l.firstName, l.lastName, l.moduleNo1, l.moduleNo2, l.email
            from lecturertable l
            where l.staffNumber=:staffNumber";

    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("staffNumber", $staffNumber);
        $stmt->execute();
        $lecturer = $stmt->fetchObject();
        $db = null;

        if (!isset($_GET['callback'])) {
            echo json_encode($lecturer);
        } else {
            echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($lecturer) . ');';
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

So far so good - I think!

I now try and set up routes in main.js:

```
"":"list",
"list":"list",
"modules/:id":"moduleDetails",
"modules/:id/lecturers":"moduleLecturers",
"modules/:id/lecturers/:staffNumber":"lecturerDetails"
```

and have a couple of matching functions for the last two routes:

```
   moduleLecturers:function (id) {
        var module = new Module({id:id});
        module.lecturers.fetch();
        this.changePage(new ModuleLecturersPage({model:module.lecturers}));
    },

    lecturerDetails:function (staffNumber) {
        var lecturer = new Lecturer({staffNumber:staffNumber});
        var self = this;
        lecturer.fetch({
            success:function (data) {
                self.changePage(new LecturerView({model:data}));
            }
        });
    },
```

There looks to be something wrong with lecturerDetails however - the console is indicating an error at the lecturer.fetch code: GET localhost/api/lecturers/lecturer 404 (Not Found). Can anybody point me in the right direction?

My Lecturer model is:

```
window.Lecturer = Backbone.Model.extend({


    urlRoot:"../api/lecturers/lecturer",

    initialize:function () {
        this.lecturer = new lecturerCollection();
        this.lecturer.url = '../api/modules/lecturers/' + this.staffNumber + '/lecturer';

    }


});

window.lecturerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model:Lecturer,

    url:"../api/lecturers/lecturer",


});
```

And the view is as follows:

```
window.LecturerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('lecturer-details'));
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});
```

I link to the lecturer-details template from a lecturer list item with a link: href='#modules/<%= moduleNo %>/lecturers/<%= staffNumber %>'

Can anybody please advise if there is anything obvious that I am missing - I am trying a lot of ways around this, but am not meeting with much success!

Thanks!

Comment: By calling `lecturer.fetch` I think you are fetching the model which has a url that is not matched by your RESTful API. Maybe you should call `lecturer.lecturer.fetch` to fetch the collection instead?

Comment: Did you check that the request is beeing sent to the url you want?
Let's check if the problem is on the server or client side

Comment: Shouldn't you be receiving two parameters in `lecturerDetails` callback like `id` and `staffnumber` ?

Comment: @Ingro - I tried this, and I think there is something here, but neither lecturer.lecturer.fetch or lecturers.lecturer.fetch work. Do you think I am missing a reference to the module? This might be linked to what Cyclone is saying?

Comment: @Pablo - I checked via Fiddler Web Debugger, and the request is meeting a 404.

Comment: @Cyclone - how do you think I could have the two parameters in lecturerDetails callback? Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: I think yes, you're missing a parameter. You are calling `'/api/modules/lecturers/' + this.staffNumber + '/lecturer'` while looking at your server routes it should be `'/api/modules/'  + this.id + '/lecturers/' + this.staffNumber + '/lecturer'`

Comment: Yeah, a little bit addition to Ingro's comment, if you look at the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes), whenever you use parameters in the routes like `modules/:id/lecturers/:staffNumber`, here two parameters are specified, one is `id` and another is `staffNumber`, so both of them will be passed to the action which is `lecturerDetails`. Hence action for the route will receive two parameters `id` and `staffNumber`.

Comment: @Ingro, thanks for this - I think it is finally coming together a bit!

Comment: @Cyclone - thanks for the feedback. What I am going to do is:
1. Double check the SQL for getLecturer - see if it pulls back as expected when I define both :id and :staffNumber in it. Once this works;
2. See if I can pass both $id and $staffNumber into lecturerDetails properly. Do you think I will need to define a separate variable for module - i.e. var module = new Module({id:id}); AFTER var lecturer = new Lecturer({staffNumber:staffNumber});?
3. Change the URL in the Lecturer model to include this.id as well as this.staffNumber.
I will let you guys know how I get on.

Comment: @Cyclone - Nearly there, missing something vital. 
1. SQL works as expected.
2. Tried passing in both $id and $staffNumber into getLecturer. Seems to be ok. Not working at lecturerDetails stage - i.e.     lecturerDetails:function (id, staffNumber) - but keep on getting uncaught reference errors. I can't really describe what I am doing here, as there is a character limit. Suffice to say, I reckon I am close, but at this stage I am just guessing, testing, failing, then rinsing, repeating.

Comment: @Cyclone - lecturerDetails looks like this (with much swapping, commenting, trying!):
    `lecturerDetails:function (id, staffNumber) {
        //var module = new Module({id:id});
        //var lecturers = new Lecturers({id:id});
        var lecturer = new Lecturer({staffNumber:staffNumber});
        var self = this;
        module.lecturers.lecturer.fetch({
            success:function (data) {
                self.changePage(new LecturerView({model:data}));
            }
        });
    },`